# Why does the list.reverse() function reverse an unspecified list in addition to the specified one?

Tags: python

I am doing a basic computer science course and came across a strange occurrence whilst doing some basic python code. (added print functions for debugging purposes)

```
#Defines a function that checks if a word is a palindrome or not
def is_palindrome(word):
    word_list = []
    for x in range(0, len(word)):
        word_list.append(word[x])
    word_list_reversed = word_list
    print (word_list)
    word_list_reversed.reverse()
    print (word_list)
    print (word_list_reversed)
    if (word_list == word_list_reversed):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
is_palindrome(str(input("Enter a word: ")))
```

This function should check if the input word is a palindrome or not. However, when I use the list.reverse() function on the word_list_reversed variable it also reverses the word_list variable.

> Enter a word: hello
>
> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>
> ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
>
> ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
>
> True

As you can see, the word_list variable is as it should be until the world_list_reversed variable is reversed. I am not looking for alternate solutions to finding palindromes, just an answer as to why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, as in many other OO languages, lists are assigned by reference. Thus, when you do:

`word_list_reversed = word_list`

You are simply making `word_list_reversed` point to the same memory address as `word_list`. That's why "both lists" are changed when you reverse one - because they are the same.

To make it work in your example, you can do something like:

```
from copy import copy
word_list_reversed = copy(word_list)
```

This will replicate `word_list`'s elements in a brand new list.

Answer (score 2):

When you executed

```
word_list_reversed = word_list
```

you made them *the same list*.